# How to bring up salary expectation early to avoid wasting time on multiple interviews

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, salary

I am in the software industry. I am looking to change jobs. I am already employed and I am searching for a job in a different city a few hours away. Phone interview during work hours require discretion and I can only do so many in person interviews a month so I have to be picky.

I have an interview planned with a company for the position of "Junior Software Developer", although the requirements of this job posting are anything but Junior. I want to know if the pay is Junior level. In the past I've had to do multiple job interviews with a company to get to the job offer and salary negotiation phase, but I'd like to get a rough idea of salary before then, so I don't limit the time I can put into other opportunities.

What is the best way to get a rough idea of salary expectations from an employer before a job offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also work in software, and while many companies don't post salary ranges on listings (IMO, a huge waste of everyone's time) you can usually get the range. I recommend using one or both of these:

- HR screen interview: most of the jobs I've interviewed for have some kind of screen before the first interview. This is a great time to ask about the salary range for the position. A lot of companies will ask you what you currently make to be certain that you aren't out of the range for the job, but whether or not they do you can ask the range. There is nothing unprofessional about it. (If you are interviewing with a company that doesn't have an HR screen before the first interview, then you can ask in the first interview. The interviewer might not know, but they should be able to refer you to the person that would know.)
- Glassdoor.com is a great website for learning how much specific companies pay for what positions. In software - as you probably know - positions tend to have a very wide pay range, so this is a really good resource for figuring out what kind of offers are normal from a company.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to be a little tactful in your interview.  Or just be confident with it in the "have you any questions for us?" segment.

> It's not mentioned on the advert, can I ask what your salary range is for this position?

In the salary band for the role isn't included in the job advert, then you can ask what the salary range is for this role.  Of course, you won't get anything specific because that's based on what end of the scale they'll put you on.

At least getting a range will give you an idea.

Comment: just to add, when i get interviews, I usually get asked on what my asking salary is and I provide them a rough range of acceptable salary offer.